# How to export MS Access table into a csv file in Python using e.g. pypyodbc

Tags: python, odbc, pypyodbc

I have been trying to export a table from **MS Access database** into a **csv** file using pypydobc - using *fetchone* function is taking forever e.g. 200,000 rows are taking about 5 minutes to print. If *fetchone* was quicker I could have just printed the results into a csv file but it's taking too long. This is what I tried so far:

```
import pypyodbc
pypyodbc.lowercase = False
conn = pypyodbc.connect(
    r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
    r"Dbq=C:\temp\Temp_DB.accdb;")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT Column1, Column2, FROM Table1");
Col1 = []
Col2 = []
row = cur.fetchone()
while  row is not None:
    print(row)
    row = cur.fetchone()
    Col1.append(row.get("Column1"))
    Col2.append(row.get("Column2"))
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Also, is there a documentation on all functions in pypyodbc which I have failed to find so far?

Comment: What if I have just the `.mat` files, and no database or MS Access installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `cur.fetchall()` and the `csv` module to directly output query results without needing to append to individual lists (and consider refraining from `print` to save process time):

```
import pypyodbc
import csv

# MS ACCESS DB CONNECTION
pypyodbc.lowercase = False
conn = pypyodbc.connect(
    r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
    r"Dbq=C:\temp\Temp_DB.accdb;")

# OPEN CURSOR AND EXECUTE SQL
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT Column1, Column2, FROM Table1");

# OPEN CSV AND ITERATE THROUGH RESULTS
with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)    
    for row in cur.fetchall() :
        writer.writerow(row)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

---

Aside - above you are connecting to the Jet/ACE SQL Engine (an object of the MSAccess.exe and not restricted to the program but available to all Office/Windows programs *-the misnomer to think MS Access is a database but is actually a GUI console to one*. Alternatively for your csv export, you can interact with the GUI application and run Access' [TransferText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx) method to export tables/queries to text delimited files. And Python can open the database and call the export method with `win32com` module:

```
import win32com.client

# OPEN ACCESS APP AND DATABASE
oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase('C:\temp\Temp_DB.accdb')

# EXPORT TABLE TO CSV
acExportDelim = 2
oApp.DoCmd.TransferText(acExportDelim, None, "Table1", 'Output.csv'), True)

oApp.DoCmd.CloseDatabase
oApp.Quit
oApp = None
```