# Including column names when converting an .mdb file to .csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, ms-access, metadata

I've managed to convert a .mdb file to .csv, based on this post: [How to export MS Access table into a csv file in Python using e.g. pypyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112512/how-to-export-ms-access-table-into-a-csv-file-in-python-using-e-g-pypyodbc).

However, I can not get the metadata (column name) from the original file. Does anyone have a clue on how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098747/getting-table-and-column-names-in-pyodbc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply retrieve headers from [`cursor.description`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description) where you will call `writerow` just before iterating through cursor results:

```
# OPEN CSV AND ITERATE THROUGH RESULTS
with open('CSVDatabaseWithHeaders.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)    
    # ADD LINE BEFORE LOOP
    writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])  

    for row in cur.fetchall() :
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!