# Export MS Access tables into csv separated into columns

Tags: python-3.x, ms-access, export-to-csv

I want to export the MS Access table I'm using into a csv/xlsx file. I have tried this:

```
def write_to_csv1(result): 

with open ('jur.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
    for record in result:
        w.writerow(record)
```

But this makes all the row to be placed in a same column. What I need it to do is separate the row into columns to be just like the Acess table.

Comment: How does a `record` look like (i.e. what `type` is it)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to export MS Access table into a csv file in Python using e.g. pypyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112512/how-to-export-ms-access-table-into-a-csv-file-in-python-using-e-g-pypyodbc)

Comment: I managed to solve it with a pandas dataframe, much easier than CSV. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because user doesn't need it answered.